# Issue with UIButton Subclass delegate method

Tags: iphone, properties, methods, delegates, subclass

Here is the situation. I have a view controller titled "MyViewController." Within this view controller I have a text editing feature that uses subclassed buttons. The name of the UIButton Subclass is "ColorSwatch"

I have setup delegate/protocol methods in the "ColorSwatch.h" subclass as follow.

```
//  ColorSwatch.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@protocol ColorSwatchDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)fontColor:(UIColor *)color;
@end

@interface ColorSwatch : UIButton {
id <ColorSwatchDelegate> colorSwatchDelegate;
    CAGradientLayer *gradient;
    UIView *currentView;
    UIColor *fontColor;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id <ColorSwatchDelegate> colorSwatchDelegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CAGradientLayer *gradient; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *currentView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *fontColor;

@end
```

Now in my "ColorSwatch.m" I have:

```
//  ColorSwatch.m

#import "ColorSwatch.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "MyViewController.h"

@implementation ColorSwatch

@synthesize gradient; 
@synthesize currentView;
@synthesize colorSwatchDelegate;
@synthesize fontColor;

-(void)setupView{
    "Makes the subclassed buttons pretty"
}

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    if((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])){

    }

    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])){
        [self setupView];
        MyViewController *mvc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:
                                           @"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.colorSwatchDelegate = mvc;
    }

    return self;
}


-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self magnify:view];
    fontColor = view.backgroundColor;
    [self.colorSwatchDelegate fontColor:fontColor];
}

- (void)magnify:(UIView *)view
{

}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [currentView release];
    [gradient release];
    [fontColor release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

In the "MyViewController.h" I have:

```
//  MyViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "ColorSwatch.h"


@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <ColorSwatchDelegate> {    

UITextField *photoLabelTextField;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *photoLabelTextField;

@end
```

In the "MyViewController.m" I have:

```
- (void)fontColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    NSLog(@"Selected Font Color");
    [self.photoLabelTextField setTextColor:color];
}
```

Now the delegate method sort of works, meaning when I tap on a color button the

```
NSLog(@"Selected Font Color");
```

message gets fired. But the problem is that I cannot change the

```
[self.photoLabelTextField setTextColor:color];
```

property. I have tried numerous ways of changing the property, the only thing that I can do is send NSLogs, anything I try to change a property in the "MyViewController" Class nothing happens.

If anyone could please help me out, I would appreciate it.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the ColorSwatch is sending delegate messages to a dangling instance of MyViewController that it incorrectly allocated in it's initWithCoder: method.

UIControls shouldn't allocate ViewControllers to be their delegates... it goes the other way around.

Delete these lines...

```
// in ColorSwatch.m initWithCoder:
MyViewController *mvc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:
                                           @"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
self.colorSwatchDelegate = mvc;
```

Then, in MyViewController.m ...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    ColorSwatch *colorSwatchButton = [[ColorSwatch alloc] buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    // or place a ColorSwatch in the xib, on MyViewController's view... But not before you
    // you delete lines from initWithCoder, otherwise it's infinite circular allocation

    colorSwatchButton.frame = CGRectMake(/* ... */);
    colorSwatchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(csButtonPressed:) forControlEvent: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // and so on...
    // now the important part:
    colorSwatchButton.colorSwatchDelegate = self;

    // see - the ViewController is in charge of allocation, sets itself up as the delegate
    [self.view addSubview:colorSwatchButton];
}
```

Instead of building the button in code, you can use IB.

Step 1: make the delegate an outlet...

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet id <ColorSwatchDelegate> colorSwatchDelegate;
```

Step 2: draw the buttons in IB, and set their class to ColorSwatch.
Then you can skip the code I wrote in viewDidLoad.

Step 3: The newly placed button should now present an outlet in IB.  You can drag from that to the MyViewController as you normally do.

Comment: I am going to see if I can get this to work but FYI my buttons are already laid out in Interface Builder. The class of each button is set to "ColorSwatch." Are you saying I should alloc and init the buttons in code in the "MyViewController" File?

Comment: No.  It's okay to use IB.  Better even.  I think the reason you're not seeing an infinite loop is because the VC that you're incorrectly allocating loads it's view lazily.  Since you never ask for it's view, it's not starting the loop.

Comment: The key is to get that VC allocation out of your button init.

Comment: Okay I took it out of the initwithcoder method. Since the buttons are setup in the XIB how should I set the delegate? Btw do I need referencing outlets to each button i.e. ColorSwatch *blackButton?

Comment: There are a few ways to do it:  you can add a referencing outlet, then say self.blackButton.colorSwatchDelegate = self;  or you can give it a tag, then say button = [self.view viewWithTag:16];  or, the best way to do it is to declare colorSwatchDelegate as an IBOutlet, then you can drag the delegate connection in IB.  Let me know if that makes sense.  Will edit my answer to illustrate.

Comment: I currently have this in the ColorSwatch.h file:

    id <ColorSwatchDelegate> colorSwatchDelegate;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) id <ColorSwatchDelegate> colorSwatchDelegate;

Should I add the IBOutlet to the property in this file or in the MyViewController File? I really appreciate your help, I think we are close.

Comment: Np.  Refresh the page and see my edit.  Keep the declaration of the delegate where it is, just add IBOutlet so IB knows about it.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a connection problem in your IBOutlet `photoLabelTextField`, you may have forgotten to connect `xib` text field with your `photoLabelTextField`

Comment: No, not that. Text field works fine. I can change the color with no problem from the main view controller. The problem comes when I try to change it from the UIButton Subclass.